# Can I pass Python command line arguments which include '#'? (Without escaping?)

Tags: python, escaping, command-line-arguments, hashtag

I'm trying to write a Python script which grabs command line arguments and uses them as search terms with the twitter api. I'd like to allow others using the script to insert a hashtag as a search term without having to escape the hash, or pound sign.

Here's a two line script illustrating my issue:

```
import sys
print "\n".join(sys.argv[1:])
```

Example usage:

```
$ python example.py one two \#three #four five
one
two
#three
$
```

Is there a way I could get in arguments which include a hash without forcing the user of the script to escape them?

Comment: This isn't really a python thing, but a shell thing

Comment: You're right. Of course. I feel like an idiot right now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put them in quotes.

`python example.py one two "#three" "#four" five`